# If "this" becomes "it" in answers to questions, should "it" become "this/that"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

I have been told by a native speaker that these two question and responses (bolding key words):

> What is **this**? **It** is a book.
> What are **those**? **They** are books.

are more likely than the following:

> What is **this**? **This** is a book.
> What are **those**? **Those** are books.

But what if we *start* with "it" or "they"?  Are the following two sentences idiomatic, even though both the question and answer use the same word?

> What is **it**? **It** is a book. <sup>(From English File)</sup>
> What are **they**? **They** are books.

Or should I reverse the structure, similar to the original examples?

> What is **it**? **This/that** is a book.
> What are **they**? **These/those** are books.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with repeating _it_ or _they_. Your last two are possible but less likely.  _This, that, these_ and _those_ are used when drawing attention to something, usually when it's mentioned for the first time.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, do you mean these are natural: "What is it? It is a book. (From English File)
What are they? They are books." But these are less likely: "What is it? This/that is a book.
What are they? These/those are books."

Comment: Yes, that is the meaning I intended to convey.

Comment: In my experience it is more usual to use  **they** when referring to people or animals. **What are they? They are policemen.** and **this/that** when referring to inanimate objects such as your examples.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, the difference between "they/it" and "this/that/those/these" is that "it"and "they" aren't used to point at things or people unlike "this/that/those/these". Right?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my original comment, they are used when drawing someone's attention to the thing.